# Serializer that sees private data, has parsable output, supports generic collections, and supports custom serialization

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I need a very specific kind of .NET serializer.

My requirements:

1. shouldn't skip private data
2. output should be human-readable (or at least, easily parsable), preferably XML
3. should support generic collections (no need to be easy, but it should be possible)
4. should support custom-implemented serialization for specific classes.

I need (2) for my elaborate version-tolerance scheme and (4) because I need to implement custom optimized serialization for a huge object (array) that I need to serialize.

XmlSerializer fails (1).
BinaryFormatter fails (2).
SoapFormatter fails (3) and seems to be deprecated.
DataContractSerializer fails (4) AFAIK.
NetDataContractSerializer seems to fail (2) because I read it's not "interoperable" (though it does use XML??)
Protobuf-net fails (2).

**Could you recommend a serializer to use?**
Also: *How is NetDataContractSerializer not interoperable?* Please give me an example where it breaks interoperability.

Note: all of those serializers support version tolerance in one way or another, but I need more advanced version tolerance features. See [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583694/backwards-compatibility-in-net-with-binaryformatter) if you care about why.

**Edit:** It turns out that both DataContractSerializer and NetDataContractSerializer support both (2) and (4) so my question is solved.

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel, but sometimes you might need to build a specialized one.

Comment: Protocol buffers are pretty easy to parse, even though they're not human-readable in their normal binary form. You could always write some XML conversion code if you needed to - it wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I'll look into the binary representation used by protobuf. What do you mean by "XML conversion code"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a custom serializer, I think you need custom serialization methods in your classes.

For example: if you're using `XmlSerializer`, you can implement `IXmlSerializable` on your data class, and implement methods by hand that can cover any combination of versions, private or public data, or anything else.  Similarly `ISerializable` can be used to customize behaviour if you're using binary serialization.

If you need to support generic collections, you could implement a class defined something like this to solve the problem (assuing the Xml serializer for sake of example):

```
public class FooList : List<Foo>, IXmlSerializable
```

This allows you to customize the serialization of a semi-generic collection class.  Or, perhaps more reusable:

```
public class CustomSerializableList<T> : List<T>, IXmlSerializable where T : IXmlSerializable
```

... which gives you a generic list whose contents are guaranteed to be `IXmlSerializable`, which means the implementation of `IXmlSerializable` for the list itself is quite straightforward.

Comment: Yes, I *could* do all the serialization manually (all my serialized classes have important private data), but that would be a lot of unnecessary code that triplicates every field - once for the declaration, once for the serialization, and once for the deserialization. I hope to avoid that.